# Check if any string in a list is contained within any string in another list

Tags: python, string, list, substring

I have a list of news titles and would like to check if any title contains any of the keywords in a list.

e.g.

```
newstitle =['Python is awesome', 'apple is tasty', 'Tom cruise has new movie']
tag = ['Python','Orange', 'android']
```

If any keywords in `tag` are in `newstitle`, I want it to return `True`.

I know how to do it with a single tag using:

```
any('Python' in x for x in newstitle)
```

But how to do it with multiple keywords?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below code should achieve the required:

`any(t in x for x in newstitle for t in tag)`

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

> A list comprehension consists of brackets containing an expression
>   followed by a for clause, then zero or more for or if clauses. The
>   result will be a new list resulting from evaluating the expression in
>   the context of the for and if clauses which follow it.

Comment: I am confused at the beginning but I get it!  Thanks

Comment: See also https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/.

Answer (score 0):

for each newstitle in the list iterate through tag list for tag values in newstitle.

```
newstitles = ['Python is awesome', 'apple is tasty', 'Tom cruise has new movie']
tags = ['Python', 'Orange', 'android']

for newstitle in newstitles:
   for tag in tags:
      if newstitle.find(tag) != -1:
           #Do your operation...
```

Comment: code only doesn't answer the question require to add some explanation

Comment: for each newstitle in the list we loop for tag list to see if tag values are in the newstitle...

Comment: just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63315121/edit) to add the description on the question

Answer (score 0):

With regex (regular expressions), you can also check each newstitle for tags with

```
import re
for newstitle in newstitles:
    re.search('|'.join(tags), newstitle)`
```